# How to replace nth occurrence in the xml template in Java?

Tags: java, regex, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

Here I am doing automation with Java, serenity with rest-assured.
So I want to replace the 2nd `<p>` & `</p>` tags with a blank string.

Here I attached the template

```
<Request>    
    <P>
        <n>name1</n>
        <v>${value1}</v>
    </P>
    <P>
        <n>name2</n>
        <v>${value2}</v>
    </P> 
   <P>
        <n>name3</n>
        <v>value3</v>
    </P> 
</Request>
```

I am using the below code to replace the 2nd `<p>` and `</p>` tags. But it was replaced the all `<p>` &`</p>` tags(first and last `<p>` & `</p>` tags also)

```
String request = exampleTemplate.replace("${value1}", "XYZ")
                .replace("<P>", "")
                .replace("<v>${value2}</v>", "1234")
                .replace("</P>", "")
                .replace("${value3}", "AAA");
```

How can I replace only the 2nd `<p>` and `</p>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match both the first and second `<p>` elements together.

```
String res = str.replace("${value1}", "XYZ")
                .replace("<v>${value2}</v>", "1234")
                .replace("${value3}", "AAA")
                .replaceFirst("(?s)(<P>.*?</P>\\s*)<P>(.*?)</P>", "$1$2");
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/XSoH5R)

Comment: Thanks for the regular expression. Is there any way to replace last '<p>' & '</p>' tags.?

Comment: This is a very intelligent way of using regex for this solution. @kithmi - you can learn more about regex from [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/10819573). However, I suggest you try solving these kinds of problems using an XML parser.